# How to tell which player wins

Tags: java, jpanel

I need to make the game say which player won. Right now it says that the game is over but, I am unsure how to make it say which player won? I am assuming I need to have it compare the strings that are placed into each button but I am not sure how to do so. I know that the text saying play player 1 wins in incorrect. It is only there temporarily until I can make it work properly.

```
    // Array for the buttons.
    JButton buttons[] = new JButton[9];

    // if it is the first, third, fifth etc... then it is an x. if it is second,
    // fourth sixth etc... it is an o
    int alternate = 0;

    // This sets up the buttons and adds them to the pane. It sets the font, size,
    // and stes the default button as nothing.
    public void buttonSetup() {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
            buttons[j] = new JButton();
            buttons[j].setText("");
            buttons[j].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 150));
            buttons[j].addActionListener(new buttonListener());

            add(buttons[j]);

        }
    }

    // Sets the grid size to be used and adds the buttons to it.
    public TicTacToe() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        buttonSetup();
    }

    // This starts the following methods after a button is clicked and reacts to the
    // buttons being pressed.
    private class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // This takes the input for which button is pressed and sets the display to
            // either X or O.
            JButton pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if (alternate % 2 == 0)
                pressed.setText("X");
            else
                pressed.setText("O");

            // This calls winCheck to see if somebody won, if they did it displays the text.
            if (winCheck() == true) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The End Player 1 wins");

                newGame();
            }
            alternate++;
        }

        // This is the method that checks to see which symbols are on which button to
        // see who won.
        public boolean winCheck() {

            // This looks at the inputs in a horizontal line to see if they won.
            if (sideCheck(0, 1) && sideCheck(1, 2))
                return true;
            else if (sideCheck(3, 4) && sideCheck(4, 5))
                return true;
            else if (sideCheck(6, 7) && sideCheck(7, 8))
                return true;

            // This looks at the inputs in a vertical line to see if they won.
            else if (sideCheck(0, 3) && sideCheck(3, 6))
                return true;
            else if (sideCheck(1, 4) && sideCheck(4, 7))
                return true;
            else if (sideCheck(2, 5) && sideCheck(5, 8))
                return true;

            // This looks at the inputs in a diagonal line to see if they won.
            else if (sideCheck(0, 4) && sideCheck(4, 8))
                return true;
            else if (sideCheck(2, 4) && sideCheck(4, 6))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        // This method sets the game board to a new one by seting all the buttons to
        // nothing.
        public void newGame() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
                buttons[i].setText("");
            }
        }

        // This is the method that allows winCheck to see if the symbols are the same.
        public boolean sideCheck(int x, int y) {

            if (buttons[x].getText().equals(buttons[y].getText()) && !buttons[x].getText().equals(""))

                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}

I need to make it so the buttons are only clickable one time. I am unsure how to make it say which player won? Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `sideCheck` and `winCheck` only return booleans. So the only information returned is whether anyone won, not who won. I would advise you to change those methods so that they return more information. For example, `winCheck` could return an Int, where 0 means nobody won, 1 means player 1 won, and 2 means player 2 won. That's just one way of doing it - you can represent the information any way you like.